# Reading a byte from slave_device with spi_transfer

Tags: c, driver, spi

I am writing a driver for a device and am trying to send 2 bytes via spi_transfer and receive 1 byte as answer. My code is following:

```
int m_read(uint8_t txbuf[]) {
    int ret = -1;
    uint8_t rx = 0x01;
    struct spi_transfer read = {
        .tx_buf = &txbuf,
        .rx_buf = &rx,                                     
        .len = 0x03,                                     
        .speed_hz = MAX_HZ,
    };

    uint8_t *byteRead = (uint8_t *)read.rx_buf;
    spi_sync_transfer(slave_device, &read, read.len);
    printk("Bytes read: %d\n", *byteRead);
    return (ret);
}
```

While I call the function like:

```
m_read(mRead);
```

And mRead is defined as:

```
uint8_t mRead[] = {0x41, 0x0A};
```

The output then is *1* but should be a *0x08*. It basically just prints the value of rx which didn't change.

I dont really understand what spi_transfer.rx_buf is expected to be. In the documentation it is described with "data to be read" and the data type is void. Can somebody give me a hint how to handle this?

Comment: it looks to me that your printk prints the value of the pointer, that is the address of rx variable in memory, not its value, i.e., the value of read.rx_buf is an address and you are printing the address. Since read.rx_buf is &rx, you need to dereference it to get its value - *read.rx_buf

Comment: and AFAIK the type void (actually it is a pointer to void: void *) usually means the type is  "generic", as in each device defines the type. void* basically allows to pass any type. more precisely it allows to pass a pointer to a memory region where to write the result.

Comment: @effenok I did dereference it now and updated the initial code

Comment: does spi_sync_transfer return success or error?

Comment: @effenok 1. also just gives out 1 and the 2. gives out "invalid use of void expression"

Comment: @effenok returns success

Comment: also, the first line in the description here says something about "SPI transfers always write the same number of bytes as they read. "(https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/driver-api/spi.html#c.spi_transfer). Otherwise i have no more ideas :(